# Drawstring help Game freezing

Tags: c#, xna, drawing, xna-4.0, freeze

I'm trying to print some text on the screen in C#, and though I've done this for some reason the Game and window just freezes, and I have to manually close it by stopping debugging.
The game is Noughts and crosses

Here is the the draw string code:

```
private void Wintext()
{
    while (Drawtxt == true)
    {
        spriteBatch.DrawString(Text, "Congradulations: Player " + winner.ToString() + " Wins ! ! !", new Vector2(120, 300), Color.Blue);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.
If you need to see the rest of the code, mention so.

Yours, Mona

Comment: You shouldnt need a while loop at all, xna already has a game loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the existing code i can say that the while loop condition is taking you into infinite loop, because the

> **Drawtxt == true**

will always be true. Make it false when the line is drawn.

```
 while (Drawtxt == true)
    {
        spriteBatch.DrawString(Text, "Congradulations: Player " + winner.ToString() + " Wins ! ! !", new Vector2(120, 300), Color.Blue);
    }
```

Otherwise share the full code.